# How to check if image file exists in classpath through gwt client side?

Tags: java, image, gwt, client

I am creating an `Image` object to which I want to set url of an image dynamically.

```
Image img =  new Image();
if(vehicleType.equals("car"))
   img.setUrl(images/car.png);
else
   img.setUrl("");
```

Here, I don't know if `car.png` exists in my images folder in classpath. How can I check for its existence? I want to set default vehicle image to the object if `car.png` is not on classpath.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't check if an image is on the class path from the client side.

What you can do is add an [`ErrorHandler`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/event/dom/client/ErrorHandler.html) to the `Image` with its [`addErrorHandler()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#addErrorHandler(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ErrorHandler)) method so you can detect if the browser can't load the image (because it doesn't exist on the server side for example).

```
Image img = new Image();
img.setUrl("SET YOUR URL");
img.addErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onError(ErrorEvent e){
        // Failed to load image
    }
});
```

Note: there is also an [`Image.addLoadHandler()`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Image.html#addLoadHandler(com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.LoadHandler)) method which you can use to detect when an image is loaded.

Another way could be to create a method at server side that is published in a service which checks if the image is availabe, and call this method from your client code.

**A Side Note**

If you're the one that writes the client code and you tell the image url to be `images/car.png` and you're the one that assembles server side resources, this shoudln't happen. At production environment you shouldn't use such checks. If you somewhere write `img.setUrl("images/car.png")` you should make `car.png` available at the server side and not bother with such runtime client side checks.

Comment: thanks. It workd !!! Actually i am assiging image dynamically depending on the vehicle type..thats why check needed !!!